# how to use php variable in css

Tags: php, css

I have a php variable that contains a value of used diskspace available in a folder.

```
$UsedSpace  = $total/20000000*100;
```

Now i want to use the value of $UsedSpace for a status bar like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_2

So the width: 1%; in this example should now contain the value of the variable.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

review code bellow, this will help, read comment in html section

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $width=$("#myBar").data('width');
  $("#myBar").css("width",$width+"%");
 });
```

```css
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar" data-width="11"></div>
  <!--
    for php: set data-width like bellow
    <div id="myBar" data-width="<?php echo '11'; ?>"></div>
  -->
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using JQuery.

```
<script>
   var UsedSpace = <?php echo $UsedSpace; ?>;
   $('#myBar').css('width', UsedSpace);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your variable in HTML/CSS like this :  `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

calculate `$UsedSpace` and use it like this :

```
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<?php $UsedSpace  = 500; ?>

<style>
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;  /*total memory size width */
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: <?php echo $UsedSpace ; ?>; /*UsedSpace width that is highlighted*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
```